# Utilizar apenas um parâmetro

Tags: vb.net, parâmetros

Olá, é possível utilizar apenas um parâmetro de uma `function`?

Meu problema é que tenho uma function

```vb
oUtils.CarregarListaDominioAnalise(Session("idioma"), lst_cdocorrencia, 30, True, "", "")
```

Na qual o parâmetro `Posicao` pode ser definido de duas maneiras. O usuário pode selecionar manualmente no `DropDown` ou é selecionado automaticamente através de um `If`

```vb
 If Not Controle.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
                Posicao = Controle.SelectedValue
            End If
```

Mas um erro é gerado já que no `Page Load` eu defino como padrão carregar o `DropDown` com o valor 0 (SELECIONE)

```vb
  Dim item As New ListItem
                    item.Value = "0"
                    item.Text = "SELECIONE"
                    Me.lst_cdocorrencia.Items.Insert(0, item)
                    Me.lst_cdocorrencia.Items.FindByValue("0").Selected = True
```

Não estou sabendo fazer com que se `Posicao` tenha valor, continue esse valor e se não tiver valor fica com value = 0

### Page_Load:

```vb
Private Sub Page_LoadX(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try

            Session("menu") = oUtils.MontarMenu(Session("idioma"), Session("usuario"), Session("caminho"), Session("nivelusuario"), "ocorrencias_veiculo")

            If Not Me.IsPostBack Then

                btnhelp.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "window.showModalDialog('../help.aspx?tela=OCORRENCIAS','Dialog','dialogWidth:650px;dialogHeight:400px;');return false;")

                CriarSessoesFu()

                Me.trconcessionario.Visible = False

                If Session("nivelusuario") >= 10 Then
                    Me.txtmotivo_analista.ReadOnly = True
                    Me.txtmotivo_analista.BackColor = Me.txtmotivo_analista.BackColor.Gainsboro
                    Me.txt_motivo.ReadOnly = False
                Else
                    Me.txt_motivo.ReadOnly = True
                    Me.txt_motivo.BackColor = Me.txt_motivo.BackColor.Gainsboro
                    Me.txtmotivo_analista.ReadOnly = False
                End If

                oUtils.CarregarRotulosTela(Session("idioma"), Controls, "ocorrencias_veiculo")


                If Session("nivelusuario") > 1 AndAlso Session("siglaconcessionario") <> "GA001" Then
                    oUtils.CarregarListaDominio(Session("idioma"), lst_cdocorrencia, 30, True, "", "C")
                Else
                    oUtils.CarregarListaDominio(Session("idioma"), lst_cdocorrencia, 30, True)
                End If

                If Not Me.Request.QueryString("id") Is Nothing AndAlso Me.Request.QueryString("id").ToString.Length > 0 Then
                    oUtils.CarregarListaDominioAnalise(Session("idioma"), lst_cdocorrencia, 30, True, "", "")
                    Call ObterOcorrencia(1, System.Convert.ToInt64(Me.Request.QueryString("id")))
                Else
                    Me.hdnIdOcorrencia.Text = "0"
                End If

                Dim item As New ListItem
                item.Value = "0"
                item.Text = "SELECIONE"
                Me.lst_cdocorrencia.Items.Insert(0, item)
                Me.lst_cdocorrencia.Items.FindByValue("0").Selected = True

                If Me.txt_dtocorrencia.Text.Length = 0 Then
                    Me.txt_dtocorrencia.Text = Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                End If

            End If

            Me.txt_dtocorrencia.ReadOnly = True
            Me.txt_dtocorrencia.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro

            Session("chassi_corrente") = txt_chassi.Text

        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write("Page_Load - " & ex.Message)
            Response.End()
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Function CarregarListaDominioAnalise:

```vb
Shared Function CarregarListaDominioAnalise(ByVal Idioma As Integer, ByRef Controle As ListControl, ByVal Dominio As Integer, ByVal Habilitado As Boolean, ByVal Posicao As String, ByVal flag1 As String, Optional ByVal apresentacodigo As Boolean = False) As Boolean

        Dim oData As DataSet
        Dim oBDD As New clsUtils
        Dim oCon As OracleClient.OracleConnection = oBDD.AbrirConexao()
        Dim sSql As String

        sSql = "select "
        sSql += "vl_dominio, "
        If apresentacodigo Then
            sSql += "vl_dominio||'-'||ds_dominio_idioma" & Idioma & " as ds_dominio_idioma "
        Else
            sSql += "ds_dominio_idioma" & Idioma & " as ds_dominio_idioma "
        End If
        sSql += "from Dominio "
        sSql += "where "
        sSql += "dt_exclusao is null and "
        sSql += "id_tipo_dominio = " & Convert.ToString(Dominio) & " "
        If Len(flag1) > 0 Then
            sSql += " and flag1 = '" & flag1 & "' "
        End If
        sSql += "order by nu_ordem"

        oData = oBDD.ListarRegistros(sSql, oCon)
        oBDD.FecharConexao(oCon)

        If Not Controle.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
            Posicao = Controle.SelectedValue
        End If

        Controle.Items.Clear()

        If oData.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For lin As Integer = 0 To oData.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                Controle.Items.Add(IIf(oData.Tables(0).Rows(lin).Item("ds_dominio_idioma").ToString.Length = 0, oData.Tables(0).Rows(lin).Item(1).ToString, oData.Tables(0).Rows(lin).Item("ds_dominio_idioma").ToString))
                Controle.Items(Controle.Items.Count - 1).Value = oData.Tables(0).Rows(lin).Item("vl_dominio").ToString
                If Posicao = oData.Tables(0).Rows(lin).Item("vl_dominio").ToString Then
                    Controle.Items(Controle.Items.Count - 1).Selected = True
                End If
            Next
        End If

        Controle.Enabled = Habilitado

        Return True

    End Function
```

Comment: Ou melhor dizendo: você quer indicar a posição inicial da sua `DropDownList`, certo?

Comment: Sim, mas se já contém um valor, quero que esse valor seja mantido e caso não, seja igual ao `Dim item As New ListItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, eu faria `Posicao` ser um parâmetro com default:

```vb
Shared Function CarregarListaDominioAnalise(ByVal Idioma As Integer, ByRef Controle As ListControl, ByVal Dominio As Integer, ByVal Habilitado As Boolean, ByVal flag1 As String, Optional ByVal Posicao As String = "", Optional ByVal apresentacodigo As Boolean = False) As Boolean
```

Em segundo lugar, esse código aqui:

```vb
    Dim item As New ListItem
            item.Value = "0"
            item.Text = "SELECIONE"
            Me.lst_cdocorrencia.Items.Insert(0, item)
            Me.lst_cdocorrencia.Items.FindByValue("0").Selected = True
```

Deveria estar dentro de `CarregarListaDominioAnalise`, não do `Page_LoadX`, porque afinal a lista é montada lá, e não tem motivo pra este trecho do código estar fora.

Esta linha teria que conferir se `Posicao` é diferente de `""`:

```vb
If Posicao <> "" And Posicao = oData.Tables(0).Rows(lin).Item("vl_dominio").ToString Then
    Controle.Items(Controle.Items.Count - 1).Selected = True
End If
```

A linha abaixo do jeito que está na pergunta não faz muito sentido. Acho que você queria fazer algo assim:

```vb
If Not Controle.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
    Posicao = Controle.SelectedValue
End If
```

Comment: Fiz todas essa alterações e funcionou na primeira. Obrigado !